# Windows batch script to accept Service name as input parameter

Tags: windows

A simple batch script which accepts - **Service name as input parameter**,
shows the status of the service and
Prints the status as "Running" or "Stopped"

Comment: This is far easier to do with powershell if you want to do something based on its status.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt, and type:

SC query NameOfYourService

You'll then see an output similar to this:

```
    SERVICE_NAME: NameOfYourService 
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

More information on SC is available from https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html